# Linq if DateTime field is older than X hours

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have tried the following (obviously without the //), but I can't get any to work, can anybody help please?

```
    public void CleanBasket()
    {
        //double validHours = 3;
        // var expired = (from a in db.Baskets where (DateTime.Now - a.DateCreated).TotalHours > validHours  select a);
        //var expired = (from a in db.Baskets where (DateTime.Now.Subtract(a.DateCreated).Hours > 3) select a);
        //var expired = (from a in db.Baskets where(a => a.DateCreated > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1));
        //foreach (Basket basket in expired) db.DeleteObject(expired);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting an error in compiling? Running? or not getting the right result?

Comment: I tried answering this question, but I couldn't get my answer to work.

Comment: Does this work? `var dt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-3); var expired = from a in db.Baskets where a.DateCreated < dt;` If not, what compiler error/exception/unexpected result do you get?

Comment: This may sound stupid, but why are you calling the method `DeleteObject` passing the List `expired` as an argument? Shouldn't it be the `basket` object?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In this case surely you can simply do your date time calculation before you invoke LINQ:

```
double validHours = 3;
var latest = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-validHours);
var expired = (from a in db.Baskets where a.DateCreated < latest select a);
```

For any more complex DateTime operations that you need to do in the database and cannot do this way you can use [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx).

BTW you should store your times in Utc not local time.  Calculations using `DateTime.Now` will be wrong during daylight savings time changes.

Comment: I had to use **DateTime.UtcNow** instead of **DateTime.Utc**. Unsure if this is a versioning issue or whether the answer needs to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that linq-to-entities doesn't know how formulate the query with the DateTime.Now operation. To do this, I would get the values in a list and then with just linq, filter them out.

```
 public void CleanBasket()
    {
        var cutoff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(3, 0, 0));
        var baskets = db.Baskets.Where(a=>a.DateCreated<cutoff);
        db.DeleteObjects(baskets);  // You can combine this with the last line
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't encourage people to do this. Everything will work fine in testing until it crashes in production with several hundred records returning in a single query...

Comment: @Pedro - Agreed, but if he wants to do this with Linq-To-Ef without invoking a SPROC on the server, I'm not sure that Linq-To-Ef can translate the timespan to a valid query.

Comment: @Pedro, I actually changed it to just compute the cutoff date, best of both worlds..

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that a ORM wont be able to translate TimeSpan operations, check this question it could be helpful: [Comparing dates in query using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093359/comparing-dates-in-query-using-linq/10093655#10093655)

> basically you can consider that if the method you are using does not have a literal translation to SQL it is very likely that it will not be supported.